# I get different results when calling from Postman and from a Python script

Tags: python, json, python-requests, postman

I'm trying to call a webservice. I get different results when calling from Postman and from a Python script.

Here is the python script:

```
url = 'https://api.dinero.dk/v1/257403/contacts'
payload="{\r\n'Name': 'Lars5',\r\n'Street': 'Præsteager 5',\r\n'ZipCode': '8200',\r\n'City': 'Aarhus N',\r\n'CountryKey': 'DK',\r\n'Phone': '+45 12 34 56 78',\r\n'Email': 'test1@test.com'\r\n}"
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json','Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token}
response = requests.request('POST', url, headers=headers, data=payload)
```

It returns status 500

If I do the same thing in Postman:

[image]

[image]

Then I get status 201.

What is the difference?

Comment: For starters, you have 13 headers in postman but 2 in the Python request

Comment: You can generate Python code from the request in postman. It will use `urllib`, but it's a better place to start than 2 badly cropped screenshots

Comment: Sorry I should have metioned that. The python code is take from the postman code generator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in postman you have the json format wrong , you should use double quotes instead of single quotes for json , there is no single quotes in json and in postman it is highlighted correctly with syntax error.

Have you selected json from the raw body drop down ?

replace single quotes with double quotes for body that will fix half the issues